# QGIS 3.24 failing to open v3.18 projects

Tags: qgis-3

I've recently downloaded QGIS 3.24 and am having pretty much zero success with it opening any of the project files that are saved as version 3.18.

It will list the projects in the "Recent Projects" list. Projects will start to load, however will always halt after 5%, or 15% or thereabouts, often listing a specific layer as 'loading'.
Sometimes it will show the layers list in the interface GUI.
Network traffic occurs, but then stops at about 2%-3%, suggesting something is active.

Ive attempted to remove the layer which it 'stops' at. However not having much luck. The loading still stalls at some point and doesn't show the layer name its trying to load.

Does anyone know of a specific issue with regards to these two versions? I've tried about 4 different projects now, but no luck.

Comment: Try to install either [QGIS 3.28.0-Firenze or QGIS 3.22.12-Białowieża long term release (LTR)](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) versions, and see if the issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks for that. 3.22 works, although I did have a problem with that a while back, BUT your comment did give me an idea, and im going to save the projects as 3.22 version and see if they then open in 3.24

Comment: Great! At least the issue was solved using the LTR release. I recommend using the LTR release for stable work unless you have a specific reason not to do so.

Comment: loading saved 3.22 projects didnt work either. ill amend the question with additional info and maybe direct it/close it as a bug/issue to be logged with support.

Comment: How about 3.28? Have you tried it?

Comment: haven't tried 3.28, but ive got 3.22 up and running so ill stick with that for the moment.